# simple_slider widget in flutter doesn't work

Tags: flutter, widget

I add the dependency for simple_slider to pubspec.yaml file under dependencies (`simple_slider: "^0.0.1"`). I installed it(application run without errors). But there is an error when I add the below code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_slider/simple_slider.dart';

class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {

  final _imageUrls = [
    "assets/cus.png",
    "assets/trans.png",
    "assets/cus.png",
    "assets/sea.jpg",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: ImageSliderWidget(
              imageUrls: _imageUrls,
              imageBorderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
              imageHeight: 8,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the error is,

```
Compiler message:
/C:/Users/B.R.P.Perera/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.4.2/lib/cached_network_image.dart:460:24: Error: The method 'CachedNetworkImageProvider.load' has fewer positional arguments than those of overridden method 'ImageProvider.load'.
  ImageStreamCompleter load(CachedNetworkImageProvider key) {
                       ^
/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_provider.dart:403:24: Context: This is the overridden method ('load').
  ImageStreamCompleter load(T key, DecoderCallback decode);
                       ^
/C:/Users/B.R.P.Perera/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.4.2/lib/cached_network_image.dart:199:38: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
      oldImageStream?.removeListener(_handleImageChanged);
                                     ^
/C:/Users/B.R.P.Perera/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.4.2/lib/cached_network_image.dart:200:32: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
      _imageStream.addListener(_handleImageChanged);
                               ^
/C:/Users/B.R.P.Perera/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.4.2/lib/cached_network_image.dart:210:34: Error: The argument type 'void Function(ImageInfo, bool)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'ImageStreamListener'.
 - 'ImageInfo' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
 - 'ImageStreamListener' is from 'package:flutter/src/painting/image_stream.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/painting/image_stream.dart').
    _imageStream?.removeListener(_handleImageChanged);
                                 ^
/C:/Users/B.R.P.Perera/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/cached_network_image-0.4.2/lib/cached_network_image.dart:464:31: Error: The argument type 'Null Function(StringBuffer)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<DiagnosticsNode> Function()'.
 - 'StringBuffer' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'Iterable' is from 'dart:core'.
 - 'DiagnosticsNode' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart' ('/D:/flutter/SDK/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart').
        informationCollector: (StringBuffer information) {
                              ^
```

Where is the error I've done?
*Thank you.*

Answer (score 0):

Use this dependencies

```
photo_view: ^0.10.2
```

try this code.  I tested it and working perfectly

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view.dart';
import 'package:photo_view/photo_view_gallery.dart';

class PhotoViewScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<String> imageList = [
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533450718592-29d45635f0a9',
    'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1601902572612-3c850fab3ad8',
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Image Preview')),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: PhotoViewGallery.builder(
              scrollPhysics: const BouncingScrollPhysics(),
              builder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                return PhotoViewGalleryPageOptions(
                    imageProvider: NetworkImage(imageList[index]),
                    initialScale: PhotoViewComputedScale.contained * 1,
                    minScale: .01,
                    maxScale: 1.0
                    //heroAttributes: HeroAttributes(tag: galleryItems[index].id),
                    );
              },
              itemCount: imageList.length, //galleryItems.length,
              loadingBuilder: (context, event) => Center(
                child: Container(
                  width: 50.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    value: event == null
                        ? 0
                        : event.cumulativeBytesLoaded /
                            event.expectedTotalBytes,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              backgroundDecoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is it similar to that simple_slider?

Comment: I tried this one also still, there is an error. Saying that something same as in the question error but regarding the photo_view. Could you please tell me that SDK will make any trouble in here?

Comment: I did not face any issue.  can you tell me where you place your flutter SDK?  usually we place in c:\src  and make sure the path in Environment Variables includes C:\src\flutter\bin